# How can the child page in an iframe (of different domain) check whether the iframe element is visible in the parent page?

Tags: iframe, cross-domain, visibility

If a parent page has a div div1 containing an iframe with a child page of different domain, how can the child page check whether itself is visisble or not (since div1 maybe hidden or set to visibility:none)? Is it that a cross-domain messaging solution must be used?

Answer (score 0):

this might be what you are looking for:

```
window.parent.document.getElementById('div1');
```

Goodluck!